# Make a java program use more processors

Tags: java, multithreading

I am running a program that is supposed to solve a problem with the brute force approach.  My computer has a quad-core CPU.  When I run the program clearly java uses only one core, because in my program I use only one thread. Is there a way to split up the program in more threads so that more core's are used and so to improve calculation speed?
I mean: if one has a program which has a natural solution that uses only one thread, is it possible to force it use more threads without completely changing the code?

Comment: Some problems are “[embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel)”, which are trivial to parallelize. This could be the case when your algorithm can be easily expressed in a pure functional manner. Other problems lend themselves to concurrency patterns like producer-consumer or map-reduce. However, multithreading is difficult and there is no silver bullet – you will likely see better results by refining your brute force approach (e.g. using heuristics, dynamic programming, or memoization). What technique is appropriate depends on the specific problem.

Comment: It won't use multiple threads magically. Some refactoring of your code will be needed, but how much depends entirely on the structure of your program and the algorithm.

Comment: Well, this sounds like the kind of work [JDK 8 Parallel Streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) were created to solve.

Comment: The quick and dirty approach is to run multiple instances of your program with different subsets of the input.  Whether this is practical depends on your application.

Comment: I'd start reading up on concurrent programming (CP) if I were you. CP is a very broad topic that you can take quite a bit of time to master. If you haven't got any clue, start with the basics. There's quite a bit of theory to master to get a grip on the matter. A book like Modern Operating Systems by A. Tanenbaum is a good foundation to build on. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Operating_Systems

Comment: If you don't want to use J8 for some reason, a tread pool is also a good alternative. It limits the max number of threads being executed to the level of your choice. Of course, there will always be the handling of the data to deal with. (issues of atomicity and synchronisation)

Comment: There are still algorithms out there with no known parallelization (typically because they're critically dependent on some global state model, with lots of random non-local accesses). Only a very limited subset of algorithms can be trivially automatically parallelized (i.e., those with no coupling between the work items). But the details matter. A lot.

Comment: (from @vskarine) two (abandoned) projects to look at: [JAVAB](http://www.aartbik.com/JAVAB/index.html) which modifies the byte code and [zJava](http://www.eecg.toronto.edu/zjava/) which is a different compiler.

Comment: I believe this has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436422/how-does-java-makes-use-of-multiple-cores